# A chord plot for miRNA IDs by GOplot package

Tags: r, chord-diagram

I hope all of you be fine and healthy.

I want to create a chord plot using the GOplot package. My input data includes miRNA IDs. After performing the subsequent command, I encounter the following error:

```
chord <- chord_dat(circ, genes, process)

Error in `[<-`(`*tmp*`, g, p, value = ifelse(M[g] %in% sub2$genes, 1,  : 
  subscript out of bounds
```

I guess the input data must be gene symbols (not miRNA IDs). Is that right?

I would be grateful if you could guide me to resolve it.